# Why did GCC break code that calls abs function with short argument?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    short int k = 11;
    switch(std::abs(k)) {
        case 44:
            return 5;
            break;
    }
}
```

The above code works fine in GCC 4.4.7 and 7.1 and later.
It gives an error in GCC 4.5.4 and later releases:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:7:23: error: switch quantity not an integer
```

So my question is why was this breaking change introduced in GCC?

Or, were the implementors not aware this was a breaking change? If so, how come, how do they test that they do not break existing code?

The question can be aimed at Clang as well since it had similar issues with the abs function.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

Comment: *"So my question is why was this breaking change introduced in GCC?"* Well, I doubt they introduced such a bug on purpose.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: They intended the breaking change; it was not a bug (in the implementation anyway).

Comment: @BenVoigt TIL. I assumed there was a standard overload for `short`, but looks like I guessed wrong.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: There is (was) one, but it comes from the floating-point library function rules, which I think are meant to control mixing of floating-point and integer arguments in multiple argument functions, but the actual phrasing is (was) overly broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC (and clang) libraries (glibc and libc++, respectively) broke backward compatibility in order to comply with the C++ Standard.

The trouble is caused by this clause:

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads suffcient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to
>    double parameters are effectively cast to long double.
> 2. Otherwise, if any arithmetic argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double **or an integer type**, then all arithmetic
>    arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to
>    double.
> 3. Otherwise, all arithmetic arguments corresponding to double parameters have type float.

`short int` is "an integer type", so bullet #2 kicks in and causes generation of a wrapper which calls `double abs(double)` and this wrapper is a better match than `int abs(int)`.

Notably, the latest drafts of the Standard have an explicit exception added to this rule:

> For each set of overloaded functions within , **with the exception of `abs`**, there shall be additional overloads suffcient to ensure:

This exception actually is derived from [handling of unsigned types](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2192) but solves your problem as well.

Comment: Were they aware that they broke backward compatibility? If not, how do they test that they do not break old code?

Comment: @nadder: Was WHO aware?  The compiler writers may or may not have been aware, but their goal is to comply with the standard regardless of compatibility.  The standardization committee is responsible for the wording of these rules and should have noticed that there was a breaking change, but at the level of standardese, you can't "test" for breakage, you have to rely on the smart people involved in the process to notice before it is too late.

Comment: Well, I think the implementors also have a responsibility to notify the committee of any breaking changes or unclear wording of the standard. And if they are not even aware that they're introducing breaking changes it makes you question how they test their releases.

Comment: @nadder: Have you seen [the list of issues and defect reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2192) for the C++ libraries?  An awful lot of those are filed by toolchain developers.  Something else you may be overlooking is that it is not GCC behavior that changed, but glibc.